# SQL - Oracle Database 10g Group By Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently having an issue with the GROUP BY statements in Oracle Database 10g with my database.

I have four tables in this database - Advertisements, Staff, StaffGrade and StaffOnAd. What I'm trying to query is for advertisements with more than three staff members working on them, I want to list that advert title and the number of staff members who have a payment grade greater than 2.

Below is my attempt:

```
SELECT Camp.Title 
FROM Campaign Camp
LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo ON Camp.Title = Wo.Title
LEFT JOIN Staff Stf ON Wo.StaffNo = Stf.StaffNo
LEFT JOIN StaffOnGrade StfOGrde ON Stf.StaffNo = StfOGrde.StaffNo
WHERE StfOGrde.Grade > 2 AND Camp.Title IN (SELECT Camp2.Title FROM Campaign Camp2
LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo2 ON Camp2.Title = Wo2.Title
WHERE COUNT(Camp2.Title) > 3)
GROUP BY Camp.Title
```

The error I received with the above is: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

I searched around and basically that error tells me that the way I'm grouping is wrong but I have no idea why that is. Also I was just wondering was is the correct way to format the above code?

Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE: Just some more information regarding the tables below**

- Advertisements basically has fields regarding air date etc.
- Staff has their personal details recorded.
- StaffGrade shows what payment grade a staff member is on.
- StaffOnAd shows what staff member works on what advertisement by the
  title of the ad.

**EDIT 1: Tried the following after comments:**

```
SELECT Camp.Title 
FROM Campaign Camp
LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo ON Camp.Title = Wo.Title
LEFT JOIN Staff Stf ON Wo.StaffNo = Stf.StaffNo
LEFT JOIN StaffOnGrade StfOGrde ON Stf.StaffNo = StfOGrde.StaffNo
WHERE StfOGrde.Grade > 2 AND Camp.Title IN (SELECT Camp2.Title FROM Campaign Camp2
LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo2 ON Camp2.Title = Wo2.Title
HAVING COUNT(Camp2.Title) > 3)
GROUP BY Camp.Title
```

However, I received a new error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

EDIT 2:

```
SELECT Camp.Title 
FROM Campaign Camp
  LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo ON Camp.Title = Wo.Title
  LEFT JOIN Staff Stf ON Wo.StaffNo = Stf.StaffNo
  LEFT JOIN StaffOnGrade StfOGrde ON Stf.StaffNo = StfOGrde.StaffNo
WHERE StfOGrde.Grade > 2 
  AND Camp.Title IN 
      ( SELECT Camp2.Title 
        FROM Campaign Camp2
          LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo2 
            ON Camp2.Title = Wo2.Title
        GROUP BY Camp2.Title
        HAVING COUNT(Camp2.Title) > 3
      )
GROUP BY Camp.Title
```

No errors in this revised query. However, the only results that are being displayed is titles of the advertisement where I also need the amount of staff members working on that advert with grade payment greater than 2. I just assumed that the last group by statement would fix this issue, but I don't think its necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all... Always, when you put into your select some condition in the left joined table, you'll have an inner join. 
Based in your requirements:

- List with advert title and number of staff members who have a payment grade grater than 2
- Advertisements with more than 3 Staff members

I would do something like this:

```
    SELECT title, SumGradeGreaterThan2
      FROM (SELECT   camp.title, COUNT (*) AS StaffMembers,
                     SUM (CASE
                             WHEN stfogrde.grade > 2
                                THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                          END) AS SumGradeGreaterThan2
                FROM  Campaign Camp
                LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo ON Camp.Title = Wo.Title
                LEFT JOIN Staff Stf ON Wo.StaffNo = Stf.StaffNo
                LEFT JOIN StaffOnGrade StfOGrde ON Stf.StaffNo = StfOGrde.StaffNo
            GROUP BY camp.title)
     WHERE StaffMembers > 3
```

Comment: I'm confused by this. I've tried it and it returns no data is found. What is gradeok and why is it after the case statement? Also with totalstaff, that would be the Staff table correct?

Comment: In the inner select, you have two calculated columns, totalstaff, wich calculates the total staff memebers related with the advert,  and gradeok  (or whatever you want to call it, its only an alias), wich is the alias for the case column and calculates how many staff members have a payment grade greater than 2. If you can test it, try only to run the inner select.

Comment: Ok, I've tested it. The first test being the entire statement and displays no data found. However, by your suggestion, I tested the inner select and I think we're close. It displays all advert titles, the number of staff members per advert and another column (sumgradegreaterthan2) showing either a 0 or 1 indicating how many staff members have grade > 2. From this, how would I list the advert titles with more than 3 staff and count of those staff with grade > 2 only

Comment: Sorry.. can you tell me your max value in column staffmember on your inner select execution? I mean.. the outer selects only work as a filter, filtering rows wich staffmember value isgreater than 3... I don't understand why, in the entire statment, you have a no data found.

Comment: Yea, I think I may have found some error on my behalf with the filler data. Under the staffmembers column, it is only showing only a count of 1 staff member for each advert except for 1 advert which has two staff members. However, I'm looking at my data and the majority of them have atleast 2-3 staff members each.. I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that you have staff members without grades? Ok, I've edited again the select with left joins.. tell me what's your result now...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that there are casual and full time staff and only full time have grade. Sorry for that, but your solution works either way! Thanks for help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aggregate functions in a where clause. Change this:

```
WHERE COUNT(Camp2.Title) > 3)
```

to this:

```
HAVING COUNT(Camp2.Title) > 3)
```

Comment: I've read about this but I get a new error - ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @George - please edit your post with your revised query.  You are getting a *syntax error* and we are not going to be able to diagnose that unless we see the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
SELECT Camp.Title 
FROM Campaign Camp
  LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo ON Camp.Title = Wo.Title
  LEFT JOIN Staff Stf ON Wo.StaffNo = Stf.StaffNo
  LEFT JOIN StaffOnGrade StfOGrde ON Stf.StaffNo = StfOGrde.StaffNo
WHERE StfOGrde.Grade > 2 
  AND Camp.Title IN 
      ( SELECT Camp2.Title 
        FROM Campaign Camp2
          LEFT JOIN WorksOn Wo2 
            ON Camp2.Title = Wo2.Title
        GROUP BY Camp2.Title              --- the GROUP BY was missing
        HAVING COUNT(Camp2.Title) > 3     --- HAVING, not WHERE
      )
GROUP BY Camp.Title                       --- is this needed? (or was misplaced?)
```

Comment: As mentioned in my edit, the code works fine with no errors and I do agree that the last group by statement is not necessary, but I thought it may have fixed the issue of the number of staff members working on advertisement not appearing as an column in the table result